# Magento Cloud space error

Tags: magento2, database, server-setup, magento-cloud

I have a Magento Cloud instance with 50GB of space, but my Magento is running out of DB space, how is that possible?

[image: Magento 2 Cloud - Out of space]

[image: Magento 2 Database space]

[image: Magento 2 HD space]

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because even with a huge amount of space available, you need to allow each service to use a certain amount of GBs using the file `.magento/services.yaml`

```
# The services of the project.
#
# Each service listed will be deployed to power your project.

mysql:
  type: mysql:10.0
  disk: 5048

redis:
  type: redis:3.0

elasticsearch:
  type: elasticsearch:6.5
  disk: 1024
  configuration:
    plugins:
       - analysis-icu
       - analysis-phonetic

rabbitmq:
  type: rabbitmq:3.5
  disk: 1024
```

Your new database space will be like this:

[image: Magento 2 Cloud disk space]